# Nonresident Travel Money (Card or Bank Account) Solution with Emergency Cash Feature in Euros?

Tags: credit-card, bank-account, eur-euro, travel, emergency-fund

I'm from the *new EU* so my country's banks are not that advanced that they can offer me this feature. So this will be a nonresident account for travel money.

The solution I am looking for is like AMEX's *Global Assist* feature that they can wire you money in case of loss or theft instantly wherever you are. Yes, you can have the [AMEX international dollar and euro cards](http://www.americanexpress.com/lacidc/iccsite/american_express_apply.shtml) administered from the UK but they require you an income level competitive enough even for Western Europe not to mention Eastern Europe, right? So I'm looking for a more hassle-free option.

The second best option is SwissBankers' TravelCash card. It's second best because they fedex you the replacement card but in 2 days, so what will you do until then? And the card is very difficult to get for nonresidents.

Also there are banks where the emergency cash feature is tied to your bank account. Maybe that's my route to take.

Any ideas for me?

Comment: IIRC visa has a $1000 emergency cash advance feature, for any of its card (with a fee to the issuer of course). Check with your bank.